# Android Studio: send buttons from BottomNativationView to other pages

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

so I have this code on MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView missao, MissaoDia;
Button Change, Done;
int x = 0;
int[] array = new int[]{R.string.m1, R.string.m2, R.string.m3, R.string.m4, R.string.m5, R.string.m6, R.string.m7};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_perfil:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, perfil.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_mais:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, mais.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        });

    missaoTxt();

}

public void missaoTxt(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    missao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.missao);
    MissaoDia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MissaoDia);
    Change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Change);
    Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Done);

    missao.setText(array[x]);

}


public void TrocarMissao(View view) {
    x = x+1;
    missaoTxt();
}
```

My BottomNavigationView has three buttons, "home", "perfil" (profile) and "mais" (more), but none of them are working. I have the activities for each one of them with the respective names. I tried following youtube videos and other tutorials, but I can't seem to make it work.
It doesn't show any error messages, they are clickable but don't do anything.

PS: I'm a newbie in programming.

Comment: change `return false;` to `return true;`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: post the complete code then

Comment: only mainactivity or some other page too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the layout which will remove all previously initialize views and listeners so

```
public void missaoTxt(){
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ remove this 
    missao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.missao);
    MissaoDia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MissaoDia);
    Change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Change);
    Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Done);

    missao.setText(array[x]);

}
```

and do not initialize views again and again by calling `missaoTxt()` from click listener, so use

```
public void missaoTxt(){
    missao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.missao);
    MissaoDia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MissaoDia);
    Change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Change);
    Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Done);    
}


public void TrocarMissao(View view) {
    x = x+1;
    missao.setText(array[x]);
}
```